# Regex pattern to match all images with replacement holding self PHP function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a `preg_replace` function to find all images and wrap them inside `<figure>` tag with different class, which depends on image source:

```
$pattern = '"/<img[^>]*src="([^"]+)"[^>]*alt="([^"]+)"[^>]*>\i"e';
$replacement = '"<figure class=\"" . check($1) . "\"><img src=\"$1\" alt=\"$2\" /></figure>"';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Therefore, to put a right class, I wish to call a function `check($source)` with image source parameter. By this way, function is going to return necessary class.
**As you can see in a code above, I am trying to use e modifier, but it seems it doesn't work.**

1. Do I have to modify my pattern and replacement?
2. Should I use `preg_replace_all` to find all the images, if they are many inside my `$content` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this purpose. It allows you to define and use a function for replacement. The function should expect an array of matches and it is supposed to return the replacement value.

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with an `e` modifier will also do the trick.

Comment: Any examples where preg_replace_callback() has a pattern divided into parts like in my sample above?

Comment: Sorry couldn't find any. You can experiment by `var_dump` ing the array thrown at your function by preg_replace_callback. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the regular expression library, there are already some [HTML image patterns](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=html%20image).